# PowerShell: Why does [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)] on one parameter affect type casting behavior of another parameter?

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, casting

Does someone know why Mandatory attribute on parameter $a affects the type casting behaviour of parameter $b? In the example the array should be cast to a string.

```
function test ([Parameter(Mandatory = $True)] [string] $a, [string] $b) {
  $a; $b
}
$b = "a", "b", "c"
test -a "my string" -b $b
```

When this code chunk is executed it produces error:
test : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'b'. Cannot convert value to type System.String.
At line:1 char:31

If I remove the Mandatory attribute from $a it works fine:

```
function test ([string] $a, [string] $b) {
  $a; $b
}
$b = "a", "b", "c"
test -a "my string" -b $b
```

Thanks in advance for feedback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By adding the `[Parameter()]` attribute, you are implying the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute (i.e. turning the function into an [Advanced Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-6)).  If you [look at the source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/c08c7e4714e6822029f8741c3121bb9e1c4fd2b3/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute.cs#L95-L105) for the behaviour when using `[CmdletBinding()]`, you'll see that it explicitly disallows conversion of an array to a string, which is what you're trying to do.

To see that it is specific to arrays, try, for example, `$b = Get-Date` (i.e. pass a `DateTime` object).  The conversion to string works fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is rather incomprehensible that  adding Mandatory attribute turns them to Advanced functions and changes the implicit type casting behavior. Only Microsoft must know the logic behind it.

Answer (score 1):

To *complement* [boxdog's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58273060/45375):

Indeed, the difference in behavior comes down to whether your function is a *simple* one (no `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute and/or `[Parameter()]` attributes) or an *advanced* - cmdlet-like - one.

Despite PowerShell's generally very helpful automatic type conversions, **you could argue that even *simple* functions should never have allowed implicitly converting an *array* to a scalar `[string]` parameter value**, because:

- The way that arrays are *stringified* (converted to a single string) is somewhat arbitrary: *by default*, the (stringified) elements of the array are *space*-separated (a script block (`{...}`) without the aforementioned parameters is effectively a *simple* function).

  - `& { param([string] $s) "[$s]" } 'one', 'two' # -> '[one two]'`
- What's more, this behavior depends on whether the `$OFS` preference variable was set to an arbitrary separator string.

  - `$OFS='!'; & { param([string] $s) "[$s]" } 'one', 'two' # -> '[one!two]'`

In short:

- **It would be reasonable to *always* require *deliberate* conversion of an *array* meant to be passed to a parameter that expects a *scalar*.**
- However, given PowerShell's commitment to backward compatibility, the existing behavior of simple functions is unlikely to change.

Comment: Thanks for your additional info. I agree with you that implicit cast from array to string is bad practice. I worked on existing code and stumbled over it when I added mandatory attribute to one of the function arguments